Vite and Wordpress for VSC remote development
If I understand correctly, Vite is used primarily for local development. I've set it up using xampp and it works just fine on localhost inculding hot module replacement, browsersync etc
Despite our best efforts we came to the conclusion that local development just doesn't work for our team.
Can Vite be configured so it runs on a remote server, for example instead of your having a wordpress installation locally we host it on http://mydevsite.dev.com ?
I'm using a wordpress theme  https://github.com/oguilleux/vite-wordpress-starter-theme and I've changed js-css.php to

default server address, port, and entry point can be customized in vite.config.js
define( 'VITE_SERVER', get_template_directory_uri() );

The only way I got it to work is by using npm run build which works fine but takes 5-10 seconds and after it builds the script stops. Another workaround is using npm run build -- --watch which keeps the terminal alive but it takes way too long on each save.
I've also tried changing viteconfig following this thread VSC Remote Server Works with Vite projects? but none of the solutions worked.
am I completely missing the point of vite or do I just struggle to make it work remotely?
